# Woocommerce: how to make woocommerce_form_field inline-block

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

There is a woocommerce command to add a custom field, but it seems that add a block element:

```
        echo '<p> Medium Size - 70 PHP';

                woocommerce_form_field( 'mediumBagCount', array(
        'type'          => 'select',
        'class'         => array( 'wps-drop' ),
        'label'         => __( 'Packge Type' ),
        'options'       => array(
            '0'     => __( '0', 'wps' ),
            '1'     => __( '1', 'wps' ),
            '2'     => __( '2', 'wps' ),
        )
 ),
                           $checkout->get_value( 'mediumBagCount' ));
    echo '</p>';
```

I tried to wrap it in a paragraph tag but it still takes a new row:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I force the field to sit next to its paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because woocommerce adds `display:block;` to checkout field labels with class `form-row`. Also select field inside class `form-row` is appplied full width.

You can add the following css to your theme custom css or write a function and hook it to `wp_footer`.

```
.wps-drop.form-row label{
    display: inline-block;
}

.wps-drop.form-row select{
    width: auto;
}
```

Or you can use

```
function custom_style(){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
.wps-drop.form-row label{
    display: inline-block;
}

.wps-drop.form-row select{
    width: auto;
}
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_style');
```

Comment: Thanks mate it seems that my server is caching my css so I cannot update anything there (I disabled my caching plugin)  so I will have to find another way thanks anyhow!

Comment: You can use wp_footer hook and add style to php. See the update

Comment: Yes thanks mate I had to remove the label from the css and mark it as important
Thanks a lot!